# Using ILogger with a wrapper to use across various classes

Tags: azure, console-application, .net-6.0, azure-application-insights, ilogger

New to C# here.

I am implementing a logger for an SDK we are building. As a part of this, I am trying to implement a logger which can be used by various classes within the SDK. Hence, working on a console application. Used this as a reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/ilogger?tabs=dotnet6#console-application

I have my `LoggerBase` class as below

```
class LoggerBase<T>
{

ILogger<T> logger;

public LoggerBase()
{
    using var channel = new InMemoryChannel();

    IServiceCollection services = new ServiceCollection();
    services.Configure<TelemetryConfiguration>(config => config.TelemetryChannel = channel);
    services.AddLogging(builder =>
    {
        // Only Application Insights is registered as a logger provider
        builder.AddApplicationInsights(
            configureTelemetryConfiguration: (config) => config.ConnectionString = "<YourConnectionString>",
            configureApplicationInsightsLoggerOptions: (options) => { }
        );
    });

    IServiceProvider serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
    this.logger = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Program>>();

    this.logger = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ILogger<T>>();

    this.logger.LogInformation("Test Log from Base Class");
}

public ILogger<T> GetInstance() => this.logger;

}
```

The above is being used in other classes as below

```
class TestClass 
{
  ILogger<TestClass> logger;

  public TestClass()
  {
    this.logger = new LoggerBase<TestClass>().GetInstance();
    this.logger.LogInformation("Test log from Test Class")
  }
}
```

The problems I am encountering is -

1. In the console, I am able to see the logs coming from the base class and also the test class. However, in application insights, I see only the logs from base class. I am not at all sure why this is happenening.
2. On the console, I am not able to see logs of the type trace (`LogTrace()`). All others viz., info, critical and warning are working fine.

Thanks in advance for all the help!

Comment: What do you hope to gain with this unusual approach?

Comment: Once you install -Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ApplicationInsights nuget pkg., framework will inject ILogger<T> via constuctor ineject. Try using that instance to log.
further check your log level configuration in program.cs..